# Android ListView scroll smoothly while drawing bitmap in each item view

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, scroll

I have a ListView, each item view of ListView is drawing several bitmap while it creates and decodes them. But while scrolling it's not really smooth even when I test it on a Samsung S3.

My solution is to make it become an static image while scrolling. But it's hard to implement.

Is there a easy way or a better way to make it perform better?

Main drawing code:

```
  Bitmap bitmap = decoder.getFrame(index);
  if (bitmap != null) {
    if (!bitmap.isRecycled()) {
      canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, fixedSize, fixedSize), paint);
      invalidate();
    }
  }


public Bitmap getFrame(int n) {
    if (frameCount <= 0)
        return null;
    if (n >= frames.size())
        return null;
    n = n % frameCount;
    return ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
}
```

Comment: This is running on the UI thread, yes?  How fast is getFrame()?

Comment: yes,getFrame() is getting bitmap from vector.

Answer (score 0):

The list view scrolling is not smooth because you are doing operations on the UI thread.

In order to avoid this you should use the Scroll listener .Perform the operations only when the scrolling stops and only for the visible items.

Check List13.java in API demos sample.

Comment: There is a lot for listview optimization

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use a third party library like [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) or [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to do the image loading for you. These libraries typically take care of complex stuff like multi-threading and view recycling/invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)